# Restart Service on Remote System Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, command-line-interface

Just having trouble with a batch and need some clarification on 'IF', 'ELSE' and 'GOTO'

```
@echo off

sc \\RemoteServer stop "My_Service"

:query
sc \\RemoteServer query "My_Service"

if %state% == 1 goto start # state =1 indicates service is stopped
else goto query

:start
sc \\RemoteServer start "My_Service"
```

So, what I want to happen, is for the service to be stopped, the batch to query the state of the service, and depending on the state, proceed to the next step. This is necessary, as the service takes quite a white to stop. If the service is stuck in `3 STOP_PENDING` then the `sc start` will fail.

Can someone explain why my GOTO is failing, or possibly offer better methodology?

TNA

Comment: `start` is a reserved keyword.  Try another label name, plus the syntax needs this style `if compare (do this) else (do that)` with the brackets.  The ending brackets can be omitted but it's better to include them to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

When using else you need to use brackets around the command, and to have the else statement on the same line as the closing bracket:

```
if "%state%"=="1" (goto start) else goto query
```

Alternatively, if you need to do more in your if statement:

```
if "%state%"=="1" (
    echo State is 1
    goto start
) else (
    echo State is not 1
    goto query
)
```

Note that the quotation marks around the if conditions are not necessary, it's just in case `%state%` is empty.